# Video streaming on Android chrome is not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to use different streams and clients (like mpd for dash.js and m3u8 for Hls) and somehow it doesn't work for most of the streams on my **android** device, while working perfectly fine on iphone/pc. There is no error, it even loads duration time, but I guess it stucks in endless loading.
Example program:

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import Dash from "dashjs"
import Hls from "hls.js"

function App() {
  const videoRef = useRef({})
  const [client, setClient] = useState({})
  useEffect(_ => {
    let videoSrc = "https://n1.anibel.stream/dash/a265390b-45e9-480e-9607-65894e690064/manifest.m3u8";
    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      const hls = new Hls();
      hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
      hls.attachMedia(videoRef.current);
    }
  }, [videoRef])
  return (
    <>
      <video id="video" playsInline controls={true} autoPlay={false} preload="metadata" ref={videoRef} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

example of not working stream "https://n1.anibel.stream/dash/a265390b-45e9-480e-9607-65894e690064/manifest.mpd"
example of working stream "https://n2.anibel.stream/dash/38c501a6-7b86-4150-87d9-45f5aa0e6771/manifest.mpd"
You can replace mpd with m3u8 extensions.

I believe the problem occured several month before, but I've no reliable way to check it.